# How to get rid of optical reflections in microscopy?

Tags: experimental-physics, microscopy

I am running a Raman microscopy experiment with polished silicon wafers. Each time I make an optical image of the wafer surface, reflections appear to the left of the image. This is even worse for large-scale images that are made by overlapping several images, as below.
[image: Silicon wafer optical image]

How can I change the data acquisition process or post-process the data to get rid of these reflections?

These reflections do not change when I rotate the sample: they always remain in the left of the optical image.

The following image may show the features I mean by 'reflections' clearer.

[image]

Comment: Which structure in this image do you refer to as a "reflection"? If the structure doesn't change when you rotate the sample, then it's guaranteed not a reflection. Those would move when the sample changes orientation.

Comment: @CuriousOne the image is a mosaic of many separate frames, and each frame has a white line on the left. This line seems to be a reflection, an artifact of the optical imaging process.

Comment: Try to angle the sample by a couple of degrees relative to the table. Without knowing how this particular instrument works it's very hard for me to even imagine the optical path, let alone predict where such stray light may be coming from.